# How to cache multiple images for a same entity id in android

Tags: android, image, caching, bitmap

I have a scenaio where i am getting a array of json objects from server. Each object repesents a data structure with a unique id and several images url like... banner url, icon url, backup url. etc.

Now i want to cache the images if where are downloaded ones. I am well aware of LruCache. But problem is..i just have one unique id which can be used as key. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the caching module to you image loader and save them by the `URL` since its unique like this:

```
                       | Caching module      |
                       | -> haveImageForUrl? |
loadImage(URL) ------> |                     |
                       |  no          yes    |
                          |            |
                         load it      get it from
                         from Web     cache
                         and cache
                         it
```

Your caching module may be just an simple `HashMap` with `URL` as key and the image as value.